# Quarkus, cannot log on unit test using slf4j

Tags: java, logging, quarkus

I'm using **Quarkus** framework and I've built some unit tests using junit5 jupiter.

This is my **application.properties** under resources folder of my maven project:

```
quarkus.log.console.enable=true
quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
test.quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
dev.quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
```

The logger is initialized in the usual way:

```
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

However I cannot see any logging on console. This happens ONLY in unit tests, so when starting the application things work properly.

Any hints?

Comment: When you say unit tests, do you mean actual unit tests or tests annotated with `@QuarkusTest`?

Comment: Just annotated with @Test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Quarkus logging configuration only applies to tests that are annotated with `@QuarkusTest`. It does not work for non Quarkus unit tests

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the application with `quarkus dev` you need to turn on test outputs, by clicking "o"

if you click h you can see help for this

```
== Continuous Testing

[r] - Re-run all tests
[f] - Re-run failed tests
[b] - Toggle 'broken only' mode, where only failing tests are run (disabled)
[v] - Print failures from the last test run
[p] - Pause tests
[o] - Toggle test output (enabled)
```